# CComSafeArray from _variant_t containing safe array

Tags: c++, com, atl

I get a **_variant_t** variant variable from a COM object method. This variant is actually of type SAFEARRAY of VARIANT. I'd like to use CComSafeArray to manipulate it.

Now I use the following code:

```
_variant_t v_sa = /*call to the object method*/
CComSafeArray<VARIANT> csa(v_sa.parray);
```

While this works, I've learnt from the CComSafeArray constructor [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/ccomsafearray-class?view=vs-2017#ccomsafearray) that

> The constructor uses this address to make a copy of the array, so the array is not referenced after construction.

So, I'm probably making a redundant copy of the safe array. Is there a better way to construct CComSafeArray object?

The reason why a have to use _variant_t object is because it is returned by the code produced by the #import directive.

Comment: You need to use the "Attach" function. Also the _variant_t detach function.,

Comment: @Ben Ok,this seems to work: CComSafeArray<VARIANT> csa; csa.Attach(v_sa.Detach().parray); Is it correct?

Comment: You'll like Attach, but beware that the destructor will destroy the array.  That is dangerous when you use variant_t, it will destroy it as well.  You need to explicitly Detach().  Not using variant_t would be the easiest.